# predicate that output an expression containing an atom into a list

Tags: prolog

what i am trying to achieve is to sum up the total appearance of an atom occurring in an expression, then output it as a list. which will be represented as atom*N. where N is the total number that the atom occurred.

```
part(_,[]).
part(A, 0) :- number(X), !.
part(A,[A]):- atom(A).
part(A, [A]):- var(A).
part(A + B, [R]):- part(A, N1), part(Y, N2), R is N1 + N2.
```

example N-v+w+w+z will output [v*(-1), w* 2, z* 1].

Comment: i am try to write a predicate that covert an expression N-v+w+w+y to a list [v*(-1), w*2, y*1. where the N is the represent a num

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is to sum up the total appearance of an atom occurring in an expression, then output it as a list. which will be represented as atom*N. where N is the total number that the atom occurred.